# not working firebase sdk messagmessaging().send() in aws lambda

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, firebase-admin

↓↓ my lambda code..  ( using typescript )

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: ServiceAccount.project_id,
        clientEmail: ServiceAccount.client_email,
        privateKey: ServiceAccount.private_key
    }),
    databaseURL: 'databaseURL'
})

export const hello: SQSHandler = async (event, _context) => {
    _context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    fcm_message = {
        notification: {
            title: 'title',
            body: 'body'
        },
        token: 'token'
    };

    const response = await admin.messaging().send(fcm_message);
    console.log(response);
    return;
}
```

↓↓ my lambda cloudwatchlog

No result is received and it runs for the maximum run time.

```
Duration: 6006.18 ms Billed Duration: 6000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 92 MB Init Duration: 227.37 ms
```

why no result..??? T.T..

Comment: Does your lambda has internet access? because looks like a networking issue. if you are running the lambda inside of a vpc you need to attach to a network with internet access.

Comment: why do you need to set `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` ? There is no callback imvolved here so this can be removed. Try this.

Comment: @pepo vpc nat is configured.. Sometimes response come and sometimes not

Comment: @AshishModi oh.. thanks..! I'll try remove the callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop